# Line payment API spring boot integration

Tags: payment-gateway, line-api, line-messenger

I am working on setting up a line-payment for a existing spring boot application.
As per the documentation [both v2 and v3 APIs], application should first request/reserve a payment with Reserve Payment API, which will provide transactionid, weburl and appurl as response.

Application should then use the above response to let end user complete the payment using weburl or appurl and then the application should invoke the Confirm Payment API and that should complete the transaction.

I am utilizing sandbox instance of line pay and managed to get Reserve Payment API response, however I could not complete the payment flow. When weburl or appurl is accessed, we are getting "Unable to process your request" error.

As per this [blog](https://www.line-community.me/ja/question/5fa68b3d851f74c15cc34c42) sandbox environment has some issues.

Has anyone else faced similar issue? Please advise.

Regards,

Jayapal.S

Reference:
https://sombreroelgringo.github.io/line-pay-sdk-nodejs

https://pay.line.me/documents/online_v2_en.html

https://pay.line.me/documents/online_v3_en.html